# $X$ is connected and separable. $X=Y\times Y$. Does $Y$ has to be also connected and separable?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, products, separable-spaces

$I$ is a finite set. It is not hard to see that, if $X=\prod_{i\in I}Y_i$ is separable, then $Y_i$ does not have to be separable.

But for this special case such that $Y_i=Y_j \ \forall i,j\in I$, I cannot find a counter-example. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Why do the $Y_i$ not have to be separable in $X = \Pi_i Y_i$? Isn't the continuous image of a separable space separable?

Comment: @AlexProvost Thanks for your help! Not sure if this is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836220/if-x-times-y-is-separable-are-x-y-separable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y = \pi[X]$ where $\pi$ is a continuous projection. This is a continuous open surjection. These preserve separability and connectedness. So if $X$ has those properties so has $Y$. The number of factors is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, unless there are zero factors ($I = \emptyset$) in which case $X$ is a one-point space no matter what $Y$ is (and then there are no canonical projection maps).

Comment: @DanielSchepler true, I was assuming at least one factor and all factors non-empty.